# What is the meaning of this notation in R? .[, "n"]

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand this peice of code in R:

```
thing <- low_temp %>% filter(room_type == "bedroom" & score == "6") %>% .[, "n"] %>% sum()
```

the meaning of the code `.[, "n"]` is not clear, and since it is completely written in shorthand, it is impossible to search for it in Google.

Obviously `[, x]` is just base R. But the use of the dot bracket notation is not something I've seen anywhere in my admittedly limited foray into R through udemy and hadley & wickem's book. And I'm guessing that the use of "n" is also not consistent with recent R coding standards. The data frame in question comtains a column n.

My take on it is that R has been around for a long time, and like most open languages has undergone a lot of expansion without strict enough editing, which results in a huge amount of grammatical redundancy. That being the case, I feel very strongly that notation like the one here that stumped me should be systematically phased out of usage as they are unclear; impossible to search and difficult to read.

All that said, my question is quite simply, what does the dot bracket mean in the `%>% .[, "N"]`. And secondly, what is the reason for the use of double commas around n?

Comment: It means the column named "n" of the data.frame

Comment: So, the same as select(n)   ?

Comment: Almost, I wrote an answer to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with **mtcars**, is basically selecting a column by the name, but it returns a vector, diferent from `select()`, that returns a data.frame

```
    mtcars %>% 
       select("cyl") %>% 
       pull()

     [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

    mtcars %>% 
       .[,"cyl"]

     [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

    mtcars$cyl

     [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

Comment: got it. Since I'm always following with sum(), I can use select instead with no change in behaviour, but increased readability of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Let `df = low_temp %>% filter(room_type == "bedroom" & score == "6")`
then `.[, "n"]` means `df[, "n"]` (== `df$n`)